# Tensorflow custom filter layer definition like glcm or gabor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, glcm, gabor-filter

I want to apply various filters like [GLCM](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycomatrix) or [Gabor filter bank](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.gabor_kernel) as a custom layer in Tensorflow, but I could not find enough custom layer samples. How can I apply these type of filters as a layer?

The process of generating GLCM is defined in the scikit-image library as follows:

```
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
from skimage import data
#load image
img = data.brick()
#result glcm
glcm = greycomatrix(img, distances=[5], angles=[0], levels=256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
```

The use of Gabor filter bank is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage import data
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage.filters import gabor_kernel

shrink = (slice(0, None, 3), slice(0, None, 3))
brick = img_as_float(data.brick())[shrink]
grass = img_as_float(data.grass())[shrink]
gravel = img_as_float(data.gravel())[shrink]
image_names = ('brick', 'grass', 'gravel')
images = (brick, grass, gravel)

def power(image, kernel):
    # Normalize images for better comparison.
    image = (image - image.mean()) / image.std()
    return np.sqrt(ndi.convolve(image, np.real(kernel), mode='wrap')**2 +
                   ndi.convolve(image, np.imag(kernel), mode='wrap')**2)

# Plot a selection of the filter bank kernels and their responses.
results = []
kernel_params = []
for theta in (0, 1):
    theta = theta / 4. * np.pi
    for sigmax in (1, 3):
        for sigmay in (1, 3):
            for frequency in (0.1, 0.4):
                kernel = gabor_kernel(frequency, theta=theta,sigma_x=sigmax, sigma_y=sigmay)
                params = 'theta=%d,f=%.2f\nsx=%.2f sy=%.2f' % (theta * 180 / np.pi, frequency,sigmax, sigmay)
                kernel_params.append(params)
                # Save kernel and the power image for each image
                results.append((kernel, [power(img, kernel) for img in images]))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=4, figsize=(5, 6))
plt.gray()
fig.suptitle('Image responses for Gabor filter kernels', fontsize=12)
axes[0][0].axis('off')
# Plot original images
for label, img, ax in zip(image_names, images, axes[0][1:]):
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.set_title(label, fontsize=9)
    ax.axis('off')
for label, (kernel, powers), ax_row in zip(kernel_params, results, axes[1:]):
    # Plot Gabor kernel
    ax = ax_row[0]
    ax.imshow(np.real(kernel))
    ax.set_ylabel(label, fontsize=7)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    # Plot Gabor responses with the contrast normalized for each filter
    vmin = np.min(powers)
    vmax = np.max(powers)
    for patch, ax in zip(powers, ax_row[1:]):
        ax.imshow(patch, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
        ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

How do I define these and similar filters in tensorflow.

I tried above code but it didnt gave the same results like : https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_gabor.html

[image]

I got this: [image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Input, layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from scipy import ndimage as ndi

from skimage import data
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage.filters import gabor_kernel

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'


def gfb_filter(shape,size=3, tlist=[1,2,3], slist=[2,5],flist=[0.01,0.25],dtype=None):
    print(shape)
    fsize=np.ones([size,size])
    kernels = []
    for theta in tlist:
        theta = theta / 4. * np.pi
        for sigma in slist:
            for frequency in flist:
                kernel = np.real(gabor_kernel(frequency, theta=theta,sigma_x=sigma, sigma_y=sigma))
                kernels.append(kernel)
    gfblist = []
    for k, kernel in enumerate(kernels):
        ck=ndi.convolve(fsize, kernel, mode='wrap')
        gfblist.append(ck)
    
    gfblist=np.asarray(gfblist).reshape(size,size,1,len(gfblist))
    print(gfblist.shape)
    return K.variable(gfblist, dtype='float32')


dimg=img_as_float(data.brick())
input_mat = dimg.reshape((1, 512, 512, 1))

def build_model():
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(512,512,1))
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=12, 
                      kernel_size = 3,
                      kernel_initializer=gfb_filter,
                      strides=1, 
                      padding='valid') (input_tensor)

    model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=x)
    return model

model = build_model()
out = model.predict(input_mat)
print(out)

o1=out.reshape(12,510,510)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(dimg)

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(o1[0,:,:])

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.imshow(o1[6,:,:])

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.imshow(o1[10,:,:])
```

Comment: When you say "layer", I assume that you mean a `tf.keras` layer?

Comment: @Lescurel yes it is.

Comment: There is plenty of reason as to why your code  does not produce the same results as the scikit example : they are quite different! You are not using the same values for `theta`, `frequency` or `sigma`, you are doing a cross-correlation in the real domain vs a completely different op in the scikit example (square root of the convolution with both the real and the imaginary part of the kernel). You are also changing the kernel when you convolve it with a fixed size array of 1. Not as well that by using a Conv2D layer, your filter bank will change during training. Is it something that you want?

Comment: It's called gabor filter bank but it shouldn't do the process like conv2d filters. What I really want is to define a new type of layer rather than a new conv2d filter.

Comment: You are doing an apple to orange comparison : you are not using the same values for theta, sigma and freq in your test compared to the script you linked. Start by changing those values. I want to help you, but you need to have sane bases.

Comment: You are right. They did this with a pytorch in a layer as gaborNet. https://github.com/iKintosh/GaborNet

Answer (score 1):

You can read the documentation about writing a [custom layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers#implementing_custom_layers), and about [Making new Layers and Models via subclassing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models)

Here is a simple implementation of the Gabor filter bank based on your code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from skimage.filters import gabor_kernel
class GaborFilterBank(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        # assumption: shape is NHWC 
        self.n_channel = input_shape[-1]
        self.kernels = []
        for theta in range(4):
            theta = theta / 4.0 * np.pi
            for sigma in (1, 3):
                for frequency in (0.05, 0.25):
                    kernel = np.real(
                        gabor_kernel(
                            frequency, theta=theta, sigma_x=sigma, sigma_y=sigma
                        )
                    ).astype(np.float32)
                    # tf.nn.conv2d does crosscorrelation, not convolution, so flipping 
                    # the kernel is needed
                    kernel = np.flip(kernel)
                    # we stack the kernel on itself to match the number of channel of
                    # the input
                    kernel = np.stack((kernel,)*self.n_channel, axis=-1)
                    # print(kernel.shape)
                    # adding the number of out channel, here 1.
                    kernel = kernel[:, :, : , np.newaxis] 
                    # because the kernel shapes are different, we can't do the conv op
                    # in one go, so we stack the kernels in a list
                    self.kernels.append(tf.Variable(kernel, trainable=False))

    def call(self, x):
        out_list = []
        for kernel in self.kernels:
            out_list.append(tf.nn.conv2d(x, kernel, strides=1, padding="SAME"))
        # output is [batch_size, H, W, 16] where 16 is the number of filters
        # 16 = n_theta * n_sigma * n_freq = 4 * 2 * 2 
        return tf.concat(out_list,axis=-1)
```

There is some differences though:

- tensorflow does not have a "wrap" mode for convolution. I used "SAME" which is akin to "constant" with a padding value of 0 in`scipy`. Its possible to provide your own padding, so it is definitely possible to mimic the "wrap" mode, I let that as an exercise to the reader.
- `tf.nn.conv2d` expect a 4D input, so I add a batch dimension and a channel dimension to the img as an input.
- the filters for `tf.nn.conv2d` must follow the shape `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`. In that case, I use the number of channel of the input as `in_channels`. `out_channels` could be equal to the number of filters in the filter bank, but because their shape is not constant, it is easier to concatenate them afterwards, so I set it to 1. It means that the output of the layer is `[N,H,W,C]` where C is the number of filters in the bank (in your example, 16).
- `tf.nn.conv2d` is not a real convolution, but a cross-correlation (see the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution)), so flipping the filters before hand is needed to get an actual convolution.

---

I'm adding a quick example on how to use it:

```py
# defining the model 
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512,512,1))
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3,3), padding="SAME")(inp)
g = GaborFilterBank()(conv)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=g)

# calling the model with an example Image
img = img_as_float(data.brick())
img_nhwc = img[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis]
out = model(img_nhwc)
# out shape is [1,512,512,16]
```

Comment: How should I add this custom layer to the model when I want to apply 1x1 stride and 5x5 patches/window for example?

Comment: Don't we need to define the kernel dimensions of the gabor filter bank for the conv2d part?

Comment: I added some comments and a quick example. I also changed the code a bit so the output is more in phase to rthe Conv layer of TF. In that case, the filter dimensions are defined in the build function, I added some comments on why I implemented the thing that way.

Comment: Thank you for the response but there is an error massge ==> TypeError: Input 'filter' of 'Conv2D' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'input'.

Comment: What is your version of tensorflow?

Comment: Just cast the `input` as a `float32`. I use tf 2.2.0.

Comment: is it tensorflow-gpu or tensorflow?

Comment: `tensorflow-gpu`. But I also tried with `tensorflow-2.3-0` (without gpu support), and got no issue.

Comment: I got tensorflow-2.3-0 but always I got errors like 2020-12-01 14:20:46.461446: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX22020-12-01 14:20:46.464951: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:147] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance

Comment: Those are not errors, its just some logs and warnings from tensorflow.  Usually, because you are using a prebuilt binary (installed with pip for example). Nothing to worry about.

Comment: I tried to write a code similar to what I wanted and added it to the question part, but  it is a definition of a filter bank for conv2d rather than a separe Layer. Similarly I need to define a gabor/glcm layer.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to what is your problem with my answer. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Neither the code that I wrote nor the code you wrote does not perform a convolution process as in the first picture. For both codes, the result is as in the picture below. For example, the results of some of the gabor filters for the brick image should focus on the horizontal or vertical edges. However, both codes produce results that are very different from what is wanted for some reason. We have an error in this layer definition but where is it? I have a little difficulty in fully explaining my problem so I apologize.